# Get specific value from location.path() - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple line of code that gets me the current path location using AngularJS :

```
$location.path()
```

Which results in the following format: `/stringValue/intValue/stringValue` for example - `test/1234/testing`

What would be the simplest way to extract the `intValue` from what $location.path() returns?

Comment: What about `$location.path().split('/')[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

This will extract numbers from you url:

```js
var r = /\d+/;
var s = "/string/12345/string2";
alert (s.match(r));
```